# iOS - error during archiving noting UAPushLocalization.bundle/en.lproj/Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I created a new set of controllers and when I tried to archive the new code, I got this error which happened when the archiving was going over those controllers:

```
error: open /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Marketing-eusiyfrkjsbjfxdgpauubwhvpazb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Marketing/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Marketing.app/UAPushLocalization.bundle/en.lproj/Localizable.strings: No such file or directory
```

I understand that it is talking about the push-enabling library. And something about some localization setting.

But I have no idea how to fix this. 
Would anyone be able to suggest how to fix this?

And here is the screen shot of this reference highlighted in red in the Build Phases --> Copy Bundle Resources list.

[image]

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode has some weird issues with localization from time to time. I would recommend you to copy all the text in the EN localization file (expand the localization strings file and select the english one "en"). Paste it somewhere, right click the file, show in finder, delete, select the localizations file, uncheck localization for english, clean your project, select the localization file, check the english one (a new file will be created) and paste your strings here.

Also make sure there are no typos in it.

Comment: thank you - would you know where the localization file is located? I never created one.

Comment: on your files browser on the left, look for a "Localizable.strings" file. There should at least be one by default. If there is none, create one. File -> New -> iOS -> Strings File. Btw it can be totally empty.